# Signature file entry for "member _.Yield(()) = ()"?

Tags: f#

Most computation expression examples with custom operators start with this type of a `Yield`:

```
type Foo() =
    member _.Yield(()) = ()
```

If I wanted to create an .fsi file for this, what would be the signature of `Yield`?

My IDE says it's `unit -> unit` (and the parentheses are redundant), but if I use this in my .fsi:

```
type Foo =
    member Yield: unit -> unit
```

It complains about the implementation being missing:

> Module requires a value member Foo.Yield: unit -> unit

And, if I simplify the implementation to:

```
type Foo() =
    member _.Yield() = ()
```

I can't actually use the expression with custom operators:

> The member or object constructor 'Yield' takes 0 argument(s) but is here given 1. The required signature is 'member Foo.Yield: unit -> unit'.

So, without using generics, what signature can I use in the .fsi that would satisfy the compiler and get my expression to run?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need `Yield(())`? If this requires an actual argument of type `unit`, I suspect its type signature can't be expressed in F#.

Comment: @BrianBerns Every example of a `CustomOperation` in a CE I've seen requires it.  Here's an example: https://sleepyfran.github.io/blog/posts/fsharp/ce-in-fsharp/.  The author says, "We need to also implement yield since it’s a requirement for having custom operations working...".  Sounds like a bit of a gap in the type system if it can't be expressed?

Comment: @BrianBerns By the way, your post on state monads helped me enormously when I was getting started with CEs a year ago.  Thank you for that.

Comment: That's interesting. I haven't used `CustomOperation` before, so I'm surprised that `Yield` is required. I know you said you don't want to use generics, but it looks like `Yield(_)` instead of `Yield(())` would solve the problem. I think you've hit a limitation in the F# language, so you might want to open an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues) on this in GitHub.  (And I'm glad you found my blog post useful!)

Comment: No, it's not redundant. The IDE must be wrong.
`(())` compiles to an actual parameter containing a `unit`, whereas `()` compiles to an "empty" parameter.